# Andriod material toolbar isn't showing subtitle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar, material-components-android

I have a screen where I have to show screen's name in title and company's name in subtitle. But the problem is that subtitle isn't shown on virtual device, but it appears in xml editor.

Screen from device: [image: Screen from device]

Screen from XML editor: [image: Screen from XML editor]

I set subtitle programmatically like this:

```
when(screenName) {
            "loginFragment" -> {binding.ablMain.visibility = View.GONE}
            "routesFragment" -> {
                binding.ablMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.mtbMain.title = "Available routes"
                binding.mtbMain.subtitle = "Company name"
            }
            "ordersListFragment" -> {
                binding.ablMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.mtbMain.title = "Orders"
                binding.mtbMain.subtitle = null
            }
            "orderFragment" -> {
                binding.ablMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.mtbMain.title = "Order"
                binding.mtbMain.subtitle = null
            }
        }
```

And however, setting the title with `mtbMain.title` works perfectly, but with subtitle doesn't. I tried to remove part of code, where I set the subtitle just to check if it'll work with xml only, but it also doesn't.

XML code:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dl_main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/abl_main"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.PrimarySurface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/mtb_main"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24"
            app:subtitle="text"
            app:subtitleTextAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
            app:title="Sample text" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>...
```

How to set subtitle the right way?

Answer (score 0):

> **Android Toolbar** has build in capability for setting **subTitle** .

```
supportActionBar?.setSubtitle(R.string.sub_title_string)
```

Also make sure to don't use NoActionBar theme in Manifest against that Activity.

and if you are using custom toolbar then don't pass null to below method

```
binding.mtbMain.subtitle = null
```